# How to get data from sub-table?

Tags: sql, teradata

i have "transaction" table and it has date_of_transaction, transaction_number, item_number columns. it has rows. also i have "item" sub-table. they linked with "item_number". there are item_name and item_category columns for "item" table. i want to print rows with item_name and transaction_number. how can i make it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
select transaction_number, item_name
from transaction t 
join item i on t.item_number = i.item_number
```

Comment: in answer set, also i need to print item_name

Comment: It is there in the second column, isn't it?

Comment: didn't notice thank you